# How to get this SQL to Query Builder Laravel 5.5

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, multiple-tables

I have this SQL query but had no idea how to write it in Laravel Query Builder...

```
SELECT c."nombreCategoria" AS categoria,
    o.nombre AS articulo,
    ddr.descripcion,
    ddr.talla_id,
    ddr.cantidad
   FROM categorias c,
    objetos o,
    donativo_realizados dr,
    detalle_donativo_realizados ddr
  WHERE c.id = o.categoria_id AND o.id = ddr.objeto_id AND ddr."donativoRealizado_id" = dr.id AND dr.id = $id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the eloquent query in this way:

```
$query = DB::table('categorias as c')
           ->join('objetos as o', 'c.id', '=', 'o.id')
           ->join('detalle_donativo_realizados as ddr', 'ddr.objeto_id', '=', 'o.id')
           ->join('donativo_realizados as dr', 'dr.id', '=', 'ddr.donativoRealizado_id')
           ->select('c."nombreCategoria"  as categoria', 'o.nombre AS articulo', 'ddr.descripcion', 'ddr.talla_id', 'ddr.cantidad')
           ->get();
```